# Android S - 11.0.99 - API 31 - No encontrada en Android SDK

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, sdk

En mi proyecto de `Xamarin.Android` estoy destinando la `Versión de Android de Destino` que sea `Android 11.0.99 (API 31 - S)` como recomienda Google Play, pero no la encuentro en mi Android SDK.

Revise si tenia alguna actualización disponible el SDK pero no. Siempre me han aparecido ahí las nuevas versiones de API.

Version de VS:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Versión 16.11.3
```

Error:

```
No se encontró ningún archivo android.jar para el nivel de API S. Esto significa que la plataforma Android SDK para el nivel de API S no está instalada. Instálela en el Administrador de Android SDK (Herramientas > Android > Administrador de Android SDK...) o cambie el proyecto Xamarin.Android para que tenga como destino una versión de la API que esté instalada.
```

[image: AndroidSDK]

Comment: Quizá tengas que actualizar Visual Studio o necesites usar la versión 2022 para poder acceder a esa versión. [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/779964/android-12-sdk-not-available-in-visual-studio-2019.html) puedes ver alguien con un problema similar al tuyo.

Comment: Entendido, muy útil. Muchas gracias. Instalare VS y conservare ambos.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un problema que ya ha sido reportado varìas veces, se presenta en la versiòn 2019 y 2021.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/No-android-OS-API-31-option-in-VS-2021/1544107

la soluciòn es descargar la ùltima versiòn con la correcciòn en la IDE:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/